# Given $F(h)=\int^1_0 h|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx$, show that $F'(0)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f$ be a Darboux integrable function on $[-2,2]$. Define $F:(-1,1)\to\mathbf R$ by 
>   $$F(h)=\int^1_0 h|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx.$$
>   Show that $F'(0)$ exists.

Obviously, $$F'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\int^1_0 |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx.$$
I think that $F'(0)=0$, but I don't know how to prove this. Please help.

Comment: What does Darboux integrable mean? The upper/lower sum definition for Riemann integrability?

Comment: @zhw Yes, maybe i should say riemann integrable

Comment: Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is continuous almost everywhere (i.e., continuous except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$).  Excluding this set, the integrand is continuous.  Can you proceed now?

Comment: @Dr. MV, Thanks for your hint, but since we have not learnt measure on the class, perhaps there is other method?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Please put in the limit that Dr.MV mentioned

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm not sure what you intended with the a.e. result. Would we then use DCT?

Comment: @Dr.MV The DCT would give the result  by the bound on $f$ and the a.e. point wise convergence to $0.$ But this is well beyond the ken of most students at the level of, say, Rudin's PMA.

Comment: @zhw I know.  Of course the idea of Lebesgue measure alone, while separate from Lebesgue integration, is likely beyond the scope of most undergraduate level courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that the result holds if $f=\chi_I,$ where $I\subset [-2,2]$ is a subinterval. Hence the result holds for any step function. For the general $f$ use the fact that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a step function $s$ on $[-2,2]$ such that $\int_{-2}^2 |s-f| < \epsilon.$

Comment: (1) Given any $\chi_I$ with n steps and bounded by M, $\int^1_0 |\chi_I(x+h)-\chi_I(x)|dx\leq nMh\to 0$. (2) Given f, using the step function s you mentioned, $|\int^1_0 |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx-\int^1_0 |s(x+h)-s(x)|dx|\leq\int^1_0 |(f(x+h)-f(x))-(s(x+h)-s(x))|dx\leq\int^1_0 |f(x+h)-s(x+h)|+|f(x)-s(x))|dx<2\epsilon$.